# L^2 convergence with support in closed subset

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose that $X_n$ is a sequence of random-variables in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ is a complete probability space.

Further, suppose that there exists a proper closed subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}$, such that for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(
X_n \in K
\right)=1
$$
and that there exists $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ which is the limit of $X_n$, then does this imply that $$
\mathbb{P}\left(
X \in K
\right)=1
?
$$

Comment: Have you seen a counterexample if $X_n \to X$ only in probability? Or have you tried the problem with just this assumption? Note that convergence in $L^2$ would imply it.

Comment: I have not managed to (dis)prove it under this weaker assumption only, yet.

Comment: All right, try that and get back, it seems more amenable to the statement you are asked to show.

Comment: I tried to use the fact that $X_n$ is Cauchy in probability but still nothing...

Comment: What about the fact that if $X_n \to X$ in probability then there is a subsequence $X_{n_k}$ which converges almost surely to $X$? In fact, does that not answer the question, since it holds that $X_{n_k} \in K$ almost surely and therefore $X \in K$ almost surely? So it seems $L^2$ is a very strong condition.

Comment: I think, I got it.... I updated my question to contain the potential proof...let me know if I'm off.

Comment: I am happy, I think your proof is fine. I would have been happy with even lesser detail, actually!

Comment: Hey thanks, your guidance helped a huge amount! :)))

Comment: You are welcome! I think you should answer this question yourself i.e. with your attempt and accept it, because my comment is too small for an answer. EDIT : I just saw the answer below, nicely done!

Comment: Will do, but I put a thankyou note :)

Answer (score 1):

**Many thanks to @астон вілла олоф мэллбэрг for their guidance:**

Since $X_n\overset{L^2}{\mapsto} X$ then $X_n\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\mapsto} X$. Since the Ky-Fan topology is a metrization of the topology describing convergence in probability, then it is Hausdorff; hence the limiting random-variable $X$ is uniquely defined.

Fix $k \in K$ (this is possible because $K$ is non-empty) and consider the modifications $\tilde{X}_n$ and $\tilde{X}$ defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde{X}_n(\omega)\triangleq &\begin{cases}
X_n(\omega) & : (\forall k \in \mathbb{N}) X_k(\omega)\in K \mbox{ and } X(\omega)\in K\\
k & : else.
\end{cases}
\\
\tilde{X}(\omega)\triangleq &\begin{cases}
X(\omega) & : (\forall k \in \mathbb{N}) X_k(\omega)\in K \mbox{ and } X(\omega)\in K\\
k & : else.
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
.
$$
Since $X$ is uniquely well-defined, then $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{\omega \in \Omega: X_n(\omega) \not\in K\}\cup \{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega) \not\in K\}$ is a countable union of probability $0$ subsets of $\Omega$; hence is itself of probability $0$.  Therefore the modifications are indeed well-defined.

Since $X_n\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\mapsto} X$, then there exists a sub-sequence $\left\{\tilde{X}_{n_k}\right\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ converging to $\tilde{X}$ $\mathbb{P}$-a.s.  Therefore the subset defined by
$$
\mathcal{X}\triangleq \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N},\omega\in\Omega} \tilde{X}_{n_k}(\omega),
$$
must contain $X(\omega) \in \overline(\mathcal{X})$, for every $\omega \in \Omega$.  Since $K$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathcal{X}\subseteq K$, then $\overline(\mathcal{X})\subseteq K$.

Therefore, $\tilde{X}$ is $\mathbb{P}$ in $K$ for every $\omega \in \Omega$.  Since $\tilde{X}$ is a modification of $X$, then $\mathbb{P}\left(X \in K\right)=1$!

Comment: +1. As you proceed in the subject, you will realize that most people, including me, will be satisfied with the one-line explanation "convergence in probability gives an a.s. convergent subsequence". It is good to see the rigor on show anyway.

Comment: True, thanks (the rigor was mostly to be check that I understood things clearly :D )